# How to mock callable futureTask.get(long, TimeUnit) method to return a response

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, executorservice, futuretask

I have a callable FutureTask that is getting executed using ExecutorService.

```
FutureTask<Optional<Attestation>> attestationDbTask
                = new FutureTask<Optional<Attestation>>(() -> attestationStore.get(imageInfo.getBucketKey()));
```

`attestationStore.get(imageInfo.getBucketKey())` returns response of type `Optional<Attestation>`

Executing this task by calling
`executorService.execute(attestationDbTask);`

I am calling attestationDbTask.get(long, TimeUnit) method to get the execution result

```
attestation = attestationDbTask.get(AttestationServiceLimits.READ_ATTESTATION_PDB_TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .orElseThrow(() -> generateNotFoundOrNotAuthorizedException(imageInfo + " in Attestation Store"));
```

I am trying to write unit test for this but the test get's stuck at `attestationDbTask.get` even though I have mocked the `attestationStore.get` to return the response for the callable.
`when(attestationStore.get(anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());`

Can someone help with any pointers on how to go about mocking the futureTask.get method.

Comment: So... you're using a real FutureTask, and it's getting stuck when you call `futureTask.get()` correct? is the future task actually being executed?

Comment: I got it working. I changed the way I was using ExecutorService and was able to mock the Future object

`Future<Optional<Attestation>> attestationDbFuture =
                executorService.submit(() -> attestationStore.get(imageInfo.getBucketKey()));`